# Prevent LaTeX comments from printing

Tags: r, r-markdown, psych

I'm including in an `RMarkdown` document factor analysis results from the `psych` package. The factor loading table is printed using `fa2latex()`, in the `psychTools` package. The R code looks like this:

```
facm <- fa(corrmat, n.factors = 3, rotate = "varimax", fm = "wls")
fa2latex(facm, font.size = "small", caption = "Mandatory Measure Factor Analysis", heading = "Factor Loadings")
```

The code chunk options are `echo = FALSE, results = "asis"`

This produces LaTeX code that looks in part like this:

```
% Called in the psych package  fa2latex % Called in the psych package  facm % Called in the psych package  small % Called in the psych package  Factor Loadings % Called in the psych package  Mandatory Measure Factor Analysis 
\begin{table}[htpb]\caption{Mandatory Measure Factor Analysis}
...
```

The pdf file resulting from this looks like this:

> % Called in the psych package fa2latex % Called in the psych package facm % Called in the psych package
> small % Called in the psych package Factor Loadings % Called in the psych package Mandatory Measure
> Factor Analysis
> Table 1: Mandatory Measure Factor Analysis

I don't want to mess with the code in the `psychTools` package, but I don't want the comments to print. Any ideas on how to effect this?

Comment: have you tried the setting `knitr::opts_chunk$set(message = F, warning = F)`

Comment: @rangeelo LaTeX outputs are neither messages nor warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `silent = TRUE` and then pass it to `cat()`.

````
```{r echo = FALSE, results = 'asis'}
cat(fa2latex(facm,
             font.size = "small",
             caption = "Mandatory Measure Factor Analysis",
             heading = "Factor Loadings",
             silent = TRUE))
```
````

---

***Example***

[image]

Comment: Works great! Thanks, @Darren Tsai